# Can I use a temporary address on a job application if I'm new in town and don't have a permanent address?

Tags: applications, relocation

I'm filling out a job application for a store in X city. I am moving to X city, and at the moment I don't have a permanent address.

Usually I use my parents' address. But I want the company to know I will be living in X city permanently in just a few days. Can I put the address of a hotel in? I think I can tell them I have a new address once I get a new address.

Comment: What country? In the US, any UPS store will provide you with a real address (not a PO Box) for deliveries. There may be a minimum term, however.

Comment: Also, this question had nothing to do with receiving mail when I wrote it. But since the answers are all about receiving mail, maybe I missed something. Is that why the company requires an address in a job application? Anyone feel inclined to elaborate? A street address is a required field in the online job application that I'm filling out. I just needed to put something in. I wasn't sure what to put, since I don't have an address at all at the moment (except my parents', if all else fails). My parents live very far from X city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the mail sent to your parent's address as it'll be more secure than sending to a hotel, and you don't want to give the impression that you live in hotels.

In your covering letter, you can certainly point out that you're in the process of moving and will have a permanent address for them fairly soon.

And don't use a c/o clause on the address - just address it as though you're living there.  That way, there's no cause for concerns or confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer your question as it stands.

Generally speaking, the best approach here is to use a PO box. This is probably a little more resilient than using a friends address, or that of family. (What if they go away, or are not home if you want to collect your mail, falling out etc.)

In addition, there is usually a optional service with these boxes to get mail redirected once you do have a house.